# Best practice for tab order in mobile vs. desktop

Tags: html, accessibility, focus, bootstrap-5, tab-ordering

I'm currently developing a form that has two buttons at the bottom. One button for going back and another for sending the form. The problem i'm facing is when navigating with the tab key.

When tabbing on smaller screens the "Send request"-button is shown before the "Back"-button, thus I want that one to have focus first. When navigating on bigger, desktop screens the "Back"-button is shown before the "Send request"-button. In that case I want the "Back"-button to be focused on first.

Am I thinking correct for wanting to change the tab order depending on the screen-size? And does anyone knows the best way for doing it?

The code for the buttons looks like this:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between flex-md-row-reverse">
    <button type="submit" class="mb-16 mb-md-0">Send request</button>
    <button>Back</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That’s a pickle. Since the Submit button clearly is the Primary action, I believe it might be best practice to focus is first, there are questions on Stackoverflow on how to achieve this, you already have that in place. But then there is the confusion between the visual order and the tab order. While that might be solved in most cases by putting the primary button left (in ltr languages), a back button should always be leftmost. Of course, the submit button should not exceed the form’s limit to the right. Personally I’d leave it as is, and *usability-test it with users*.

Comment: Why is the order different for different screen sizes? Which button is primary shouldn't change just because the screen size changed. Having "back" as prominent seems dangerous. You should try to avoid making it too easy for the user to accidentally go back and thus lose all the info they just put in the form. The "back" button is kind of like the dreaded "clear form" button that used to be very prevalent but, fortunately, seems to have gone away. If this is an html app (you're using the `html` tag in the question), then perhaps rely on the browser's back button instead of having your own.

Comment: Your issue isn't tab order. It's that you're using flexbox to reverse the order of items at different screen resolutions. If you change `flex-md-row-reverse` to `flex-md-row` your `div`, you'll see that the items no longer change order. The items should be in the same order regardless of screen size.